# How to retrieve parent groups in Google?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-groups

Google gives the ability to add a group to another group.

For example, if we add Group A to Group B and user xyz@abc.com is present under Group A, and when I try to retrieve the groups of the user xyz@abc.com using OAuth 2.0 using the API https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups, it returns only Group A, and not Group B.

I would like to get Group B too in the response from Google, since Group A is a part of Group B.

Is there any way to do this? Does Google provide us with the list of all parent groups as well in OAuth?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hi, I have posted a question there as well. Do you know of methods to get all the groups in which a user is present in, using OAuth?